# Create Resource Group Deployment with REST API

Tags: rest, azure

```
PUT /subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourcegroups/{resourceGroupName}
    /providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/{deploymentName}?api-version=2016-09-01
```

REST call body:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "template": {
            "schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
            "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
            "resources": []
        }
    }
}
```

this is a minimal valid JSON template, if I do the request I get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidRequestContent",
    "message": "The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Could not find member 'schema' on object of type 'Template'. Path 'properties.template.schema', line 4, position 16.'."
  }
}
```

Ok, this doesn't make sense, put lets try removing the "schema" property, this is what I get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidRequestContent",
    "message": "The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Required property '$schema' not found in JSON. Path 'properties.template', line 6, position 4.'."
  }
}
```

Schema for template object is not described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/deployments#Deployments_CreateOrUpdate). So WTH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message we may know that we need to use **$schema** not  `schema`, please have a try to use the following body and mode is required. It works correctly on my side, I tested it with fiddler.

```
{
      "properties": {
        "template": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "resources": []
        },
        "mode": "Incremental"
      }

}
```

[image]

Comment: do you know how to do the same with New-AzureRmResource?

Comment: ` how to do the same with New-AzureRmResource?` Could you explain more about it?

Comment: how to create a deployment using New-AzureRmResource, I tried doing the same call, but it fails to process the template. I know there's a cmdlet to do that, but that's out of question

Comment: If it is useful, please mark it as an answer. If you have another question, please post another SO Thread with detail exception info when use the cmdlet.

Comment: I haven't yet tested this, so can't tell if its usefull, just asking

Comment: re: New-AzureRMResource - do you mean how to use REST to create a resource (vs. template deployment)?